# How to access a database view with an Azure Mobile Service?

Tags: web-services, mobile, service, azure

I have an Azure Mobile Service running connected to a database with 3 tables, on the management portal of the database I can create Views based on them...the question is...how can I access the view through the Mobile Service? is this possible with Azure Mobile Services? or should I be using a regular web Service?

What I'm looking for is a way to access it like I would do with a table...for the table I just go to the URL and I get a JSON, that's what I would like to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

you should use regular web services. Windows Azure Mobile services is meant to be very simple in simple cases rather than an all purpose tool.

Still, you could override the read operation on a table to return other results. You may want to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj631631.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613353.aspx as starting points.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the portal and just add the name of the view that you have created it seems to work.

eg.
My Mobile Web Services service is called 'PTView'

create view PTView.vwMcPeople as
  select * from Person where surname like 'Mc%'

on the Data tab of your web service create a table with the same name as the view.

Answer (score -1):

Use/ Download the SDK for Azure mobile service and then you can access your data using API provided.

Azure mobile service is not accessible directly from URL.

Comment: Azure Mobile Service is accesible from an HTTPS url, eg https://name--of-service.azure-mobile.net/tables/orders